# How to get records n levels tree with exact number of child using mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm stuck to find n-levels of tree records with exact number of child nodes.

Let me explain in brief what I expected output using MySQL query

```
All users has exact number of child users for example 2
```

Please check the following image[image]

If levels has exact number of users then that level is completed otherwise its incomplete.

here is my table

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL autoincrement,
  `first_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
);
```

Can you please anyone help me for the same.

Your help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: oracle or mysql? Look closer at the tooltip for oracle. This is a recursive CTE type problem for MySQL-8.0, mariadb-10.2+ so start looking at how to write those.

Comment: Isn't that level 3 of A?

Comment: Yes its level 3 of A it was missed spell.

Comment: @danblack it's a mysql

Answer (score 0):

If you need that and this is not some kind of exercise, just create a column 'Level' in this table and increment the 'Level' of child row by parent.Level + 1 when INSERT or UPDATE operations.

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY auto_increment,
  `first_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `level` int(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `parent_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL
);

INSERT INTO test (`first_name`, `last_name`, `level`, `parent_id`)
VALUES ('A', 'A', 0, NULL),
('B1', 'A', 1, 1),
('B2', 'A', 1, 1),
('C1', 'B1', 2, 2),
('C2', 'B1', 2, 2),
('C3', 'B2', 2, 3),
('C4', 'B2', 2, 3),
('D1', 'C1', 3, 4),
('D2', 'C1', 3, 4),
('D3', 'C2', 3, 5),
('D4', 'C2', 3, 5),
('D5', 'C3', 3, 6),
('D6', 'C4', 3, 7);

SELECT 
    final.`first_name` as`User Name`,
    final.`level`,
    CASE
        WHEN final.`childs` < 2 THEN
            'false'
        ELSE
            'true'
    END as `IsCompleted`
FROM (
    SELECT 
        t.`first_name`,
        t.`level`,
        COUNT(c.`parent_id`) as `childs`
    FROM test t
    LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        jt1.`parent_id`
    FROM test jt1
    ) as c ON t.`id` = c.`parent_id`
    GROUP BY t.`first_name`, 
        t.`level`
) as final;
```

[DB fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2xudeXK6PKWih1RFWgKEAv/1)